# Git Log of a particular file from a particular commit only

Tags: command-line, bash, git, logging

```bash
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --patch --full-history --follow -- "${FileP}"
```

prints

```
* b8800d8 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) chore(export): exported to repo
| diff --git a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| index c15b225..44691e8 100644
| --- a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| +++ b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
|  include Config.txt
| -include SolarizedDark.txt
| +include SolarizedLight.txt
...
* 300d6c6 chore(source): dirty state
| diff --git a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| similarity index 100%
| rename from DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| rename to DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
...
* 1c2327b chore: initial
  diff --git a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
  new file mode 100644
  index 0000000..c15b225
  --- /dev/null
  +++ b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
  @@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
  +include Config.txt
  +include SolarizedDark.txt
```

It shows changes to file in all commits.

How can I show the above information, but just for one commit say commit with hash `b8800d8` (can be any hash depending on commit) as follows

```
* b8800d8 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) chore(export): exported to repo
| diff --git a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| index c15b225..44691e8 100644
| --- a/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| +++ b/DotFilesSrc/DotFileTools/Linux/RepositoryTree/Zathura/zathurarc
| @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
|  include Config.txt
| -include SolarizedDark.txt
| +include SolarizedLight.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man git-log`, this can be done by specifying the two commits you are comparing between, separated by an ellipsis `...`

You can specify the commits with `HEAD~` notation, or use the commit hash.

To display the information for the last commit only, the command is

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --patch --full-history --follow HEAD...HEAD~1 -- "${FileP}"
```

If you really want to be able to do this by providing only a single commit hash, the following Bash function should work.

```
commitlog() {
    PREVIOUS_COMMIT=$(git log --oneline | awk '{print $1}' | grep -A 1 "$1" | tail -n 1)
    git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --patch --full-history --follow "$1"..."$PREVIOUS_COMMIT" -- "$2"
}
```

Once it has been declared, you can call it with

```
commitlog b8800d8 "${FileP}"
```

where `b8800d8` is the commit hash and `FileP` is a variable containing the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
git log <the rest of your flags> -1 b8800d8 -- "${FileP}"
```

`b8800d8` makes it start from that commit and `-1` limits the output to
the first commit.